# jQuery accessibility with PHP GET parameters

Tags: php, jquery

This has been in my mind for a long while now and I can't seem to figure it out myself. Neither do I find any useful information about this, out there, so I hope to get some answers here instead.

I'm using jQuery which is integrated into my site, together with a lot of PHP GET parameters to control what content you're watching. However jQuery doesn't seem to be available when code inside an if-block with a GET parameter tries to reach it.

Example PHP:

```
if($_GET["page"]) {
    echo "<div class='box'>Click me</div>";
}
```

Example jQuery:

```
$(".box").click(function() {
    alert("Box!");
});
```

When you press "Click me", nothing would happen, as it the jQuery code doesn't exist. Why is this happening and is there any workarounds for this?

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console? Do you get your GET parameters with AJAX call perhaps (resulting in missing element .box from DOM on page load)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below:

```
$(document).on("click",".box",function(e){
  alert('box');
});
```

Comment: This is correct. Will work surely..can be accepted as answer

Comment: It does indeed work now. Would be nice if I could get an explanation of why my code doesn't work, I want to understand what I did wrong.